# Scribus can't import my MATLAB eps figure and has issues too if it's converted to SVG in Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg, eps, scribus

I have a MATLAB script that produces figures in eps format. I attempted to import into Scribus but got a fatal error. Instead I imported into InkScape first to convert to SVG (no problem there), but then when I import that SVG into Scribus, the axis numbers get jumbled and the dashed lines get crazy (it tells me "File contains some unsupported features"). What am I doing wrong/what should I do to keep things looking right? Here's how they look:

**MATLAB eps imported into Inkscape:**
[image: MATLAB eps]

**After importing SVG to Scribus:**
[image: Scribus SVG]

(I'm running Scribus 1.4.7; should I be using 1.5.x or no?)

Comment: Nothing tyhe eps export of matlab is pretty awful. I mean seriously i couldt do worse even if i tried

Comment: So is it best not to use `export_fig` to get an eps, and just export an SVG instead?

Comment: Can you also upload the eps file? I'd like to give it a try and, possibly, fill a bug in the Scribus bug tracker...

Comment: Re Scribus versions: This would warrant a whole new question, even for the context of importing eps files. I can just tell you that I and many other users are using 1.5.x and it does behave well. Does not feel like a buggy developing-version at all. Just finished a 20 page magazine with three different users, many illustrations, imported vectors and bitmaps, many layers, many features used: not a single crash. I have not seen mention that 1.5.x would support eps-import better, but generally 1.5 does have wider range of import filters. Give it a try, you can parallel install.